# Menu items moving when I hover them

Tags: html, css

Im trying to hover my menu items with a gray background with padding of 5px.

The problem is that, when I hover my menu items they are moving because of the hover padding.

But I dont see how can I solve this, Im trying but nothing is working.

Do you know how to fix this?

```
.dropDownMenu a {
    height: 62px;
    line-height: 62px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:yellow;

}

.dropDownMenu li span:hover {
    background-color:#ccc;color:#2F3083; border-radius:7px; padding:5px;
}
```

I have here my full example: http://jsfiddle.net/jcak/Lmc4mj2u/14/

Comment: It looks fine to me on Chrome... but what if you gave the span 5px of padding and a transparent background, and then on hover just change the background-color?

Comment: Could you please show an image of the final desired result please? I don't really get where the padding should be, and which area of your item should be "hoverable".

Comment: Sorry, I update my fiddle with my issue demonstration!

Comment: I want the effect that you see in that fiddle, a gray background with 5px of padding on mouse hover in my menu items. The only problem is that, when I hover my menu items, they move, and I think that is because of padding of 5px!

Comment: Just move the padding to the `a` element so it's always there instead of adding  it on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give `.dropDownMenu li span` the `padding: 5px`, and remove it from the hover selector.

So you get: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmc4mj2u/15/ instead.